# Centering Three Vertical Dots With the Math Axis

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I have a formula like below

```
w(\boldsymbol{\kappa})=\frac{1} 
{2}\boldsymbol{\kappa}\,\vdots\,\mathbf{G}\,\vdots\,\boldsymbol{\kappa}
```

which has an output of the form

[image]

I want the triple vertical dots to be *vertically centered on the math axis*, that is to say, I want them to move downwards a little. What should I do?

Comment: when you say "aligned with the horizontal text line", can i assume that you mean "vertically centered on the math axis"?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Exactly. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\vdots` is difficult to control because it has a big vertical space at the top. A version without it is provided below; note that the middle dot is at the same height as the formula axis (represented by the fraction line).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm} % \bm is better and simpler to type

\newcommand{\vdotsop}{%
  \mathinner{\vcenter{
    \baselineskip=1ex
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }}
}

\begin{document}

\[
w(\bm{\kappa})=
\frac{1}{2}\bm{\kappa}\vdotsop\mathbf{G}\vdotsop\bm{\kappa}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the distance between the dots equal to the distance in the colon, you can do as follows, but I don't like very much the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm} % \bm is better and simpler to type

\newcommand{\vdotsop}{%
  \mathinner{\vcenter{
    \normalbaselines
    \baselineskip=\dimexpr\fontcharht\textfont0`:-\fontcharht\textfont0`.\relax
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }}
}

\begin{document}

\[
w(\bm{\kappa})=
\frac{1}{2}\bm{\kappa}\vdotsop\mathbf{G}\vdotsop\bm{\kappa}:
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you adjust the distance between the dots to be like the distance between the dots in`:`? :)

Comment: @H.R. Yes, of course. `;-)`

Comment: I encountered a weird thing! Your update for the distance does not work in an `align` environment! Why? :(

Comment: @H.R. Fixed by adding `\normalbaselines` that restores the standard values of line spacing parameters.

Comment: @egreg Can you please explain why you used `\bm` for `\kappa` and `\mathbf` for `G`? Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: @frougon Simply because so wanted the OP. Note that `\bm{G}` would print a bold math *italic* G.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Indeed, I had not quite realized that `\mathbf` used an upright shape.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine} 
\newcommand{\cvdots}{\Vectorstack{\vdots}}

\begin{document}

\[ w(\boldsymbol{\kappa})=\frac{1}
{2}\boldsymbol{\kappa}\, \cvdots \,\mathbf{G}\,\cvdots\,\boldsymbol{\kappa}
 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: as Barbara Beeton pointed out, this is not perfectly aligned on the math axis.  With this other code, using the `stackinset`  command from `stackengine`, we have a better result:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\vcdots{\;\stackMath\stackinset{c}{0pt}{c}{0.6ex}{\vdots}{\vphantom{-}}\;}

\[ w(\boldsymbol{κ})=\mfrac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{κ}\vcdots\mathbf{G} \vcdots \boldsymbol{κ}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the central dot isn't exactly lined up with the minus (which it should be), so a tiny upward adjustment would be beneficial.  (`\smash`ing the dots and supplying a suitable `\vphantom` to get rid of the excess "air" should have the desired effect.)

Comment: I think barbara is right. It is not perfectly centered.

Comment: @H.R.: Indeed zooming and measuring, there's 1 pt difference in height, due to reasons explained by egreg. I've posted another solution, always based on `stackengine` which is better and hopefully should remain so at all font sizes.

Comment: unless i'm mistaken, you are using `em` to indicate a vertical distance.  that won't yield the correct offset if the aspect ratio of the font is not square.  (and computer modern fonts at 7pt or below have a non-square aspect ratio.)  for vertical dimensions, use `ex` instead.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I didn't know these details. Actually, I thought in terms of *mu*s, but as I wasn't in math mode, I opted for em. The exact value here was found by trial and error anyway, so I can as well use ex.